# Does php-excel-reader support xlsx

Tags: php, excel

I am using `php-excel-reader`, but got error on reading `.xlsx` file. So does this support xlsx format. Or what is other solution available.

My requirement is just to read the file`(xls, xlsx and ods)` and render on html page.

`PHPExcel` seems too much as there is no requirement for editing the excel file.

Comment: do you get an answer? i am facing the same issue in PHP 8.1.0 using php-excel-reader

Comment: Yes see @DrColossos [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17670315/713573). `php-excel-reader` does not support other than xls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/issues/detail?id=154&q=xlsx) it doesn't seem to work. They referr you to [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) if you want to use xlsl files. From a first look, this seems like a better alternative anyways.

Answer (score 15):

Yes php support to read .xlsx file.

For that you have to use PHPExcel library.

I have created script to read excle file, You can download script from : https://www.dropbox.com/s/oao0eskflu8nyz1/PHPExcleReader.zip?dl=0

Comment: thanks for the example. This simple example using PHPExcel, made it very simple. Otherwise I was bit reluctant to use PHPExcel as in their examples many of those I could not run. Well I found another [spreadsheet-reader](https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader) that also seems fine to just read the excel(XLS and XLSX)

Comment: I also found your simple example very useful. I was very discouraged after one glance at the original PHPExcel download. However your example worked instantly when I attemped it, and reading my own files posed no problems. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: hey this domain is expire so how can i see this script ? suggest me

Comment: Please change the broken link :(

Comment: I am not satisfied with your answer @jaydeep namera OP asked for `Does php-excel-reader support xlsx` but you are talking about phpExcel library, did not answer correctly for this question

Comment: your answer is not relevant to this question PHP-excel-reader, PHPExcel has huge file

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know php-excel-reader doesn't support xlsx. PHPExcel would be the way to go. That being said it might be better to store whatever is in your xslx files in a less proprietary way. Taking a long shot I would assume your xslx doesn't contain calculations which do belong in xlsx files but rather table data which would be better stored in some database (txt, csv, sqlite, a database server).

Comment: Actually user is going to upload the excel file so conversion of the file is out of question.

Comment: If relevant you might be able to convince the user to use a more appropriate file format.