# How can I read XLSX files using php excel reader 2?

Tags: php, xlsx

I want to read XLSX file using excel  reader 2. I have done all the work using this library and I can't go back and do learning PHPExcel

Kindly help me out...

Comment: You can't, [PHP Excel Reader 2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/php-excel-reader2/) is only capable of reading BIFF-format xls files, and not OfficeOpenXML-formal xlsx files

Answer (score 0):

Here is a question I think would answer yours - Use the first answer by 'Jd Namera' [Does php-excel-reader support xlsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670179/does-php-excel-reader-support-xlsx)